# SO_KEEPALIVE and poll

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Hello I try to use the following code, but it seems not working, on a 
connected socket (sock) i do:

```
struct pollfd input_fd; 
int a=1; 
setsockopt(sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_KEEPALIVE,&a,sizeof(a)); 
a=1; 
setsockopt(sock,SOL_TCP,TCP_KEEPIDLE,&a,sizeof(a)); 
a=1; 
setsockopt(sock,SOL_TCP,TCP_KEEPINTVL,&a,sizeof(a)); 
a=1; 
setsockopt(sock,SOL_TCP,TCP_KEEPCNT,&a,sizeof(a)); 
input_fd.fd = sock; 
input_fd.events = POLLIN | POLLOUT; 
input_fd.revents = 0; 
int p=poll(&input_fd, 1,-1);
```

I pull the LAN plug to the remote computer, but nothing happens. The 
kernel seems to be sleeping in poll syscall. Is this desired 
behaviour, or it is a defect?

Comment: What else did you do with the socket? Only created it with `socket`, or also listen/bind/connect?

Comment: How long did you wait? The default keepalive timeout is 2 hours.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: The OP is using TCP_KEEPINTVL = TCP_KEEPIDLE = TCP_KEEPCNT= 1 so unless the setsockopt fails, it _should_ time out after 1 second (and send 1 probe max).

Comment: .... but another thing: Would one not want to poll on `POLLRDHUP|POLLHUP` rather than `POLLIN|POLLOUT` if one wants to detect a broken connection?

Comment: @Damon: those events are always enabled; no need to ask for them explicitly

Comment: .. and they are output events

Comment: If `poll` blocks on events `POLLIN | POLLOUT` on a fully connected socket then that means the output queue is already full.  Try setting the keepalive options before sending/receiving any data.

Comment: The time between "keepalives" falls back from a per-socket value to a system-wide value. Because there was an incident with keepalives placing a massive load on a system many decades ago (a completely different situation all these decades later, but...), the "default" time between keepalives is often set to a very very long time (such as 2 hours)! So figure out how to not only turn on keealives for your socket, but also specify the keepalive timeout interval for your particular socket; Until you do, the interval between keepalives may be so long they're effectively useless.

Answer (score 0):

Set nfds:

```
int p=poll(&input_fd, sock+1 ,-1);
```

Also, I'm not sure of the allowed range of those settings, it's worth to check the return value of `setsockopt`.

Comment: For poll, nfds=1 is correct.  If you were using select then it would be sock+1.